# Function calling unambiguous or a Xcode 8 bug?

Tags: swift, xcode, function

Let's come to the code directly

```
//funcA
func greet(person: String) -> String {
    return "Hello, " + person + "!"
}

//funcB
func greetAgain(person: String) -> String {
    return "Hello again, " + person + "!"
}

//funcC
func greet(person: String, alreadyGretted: Bool) -> String{
    if alreadyGretted {
        return greetAgain(person: person)
    } else {
        return greet(person: person)
    }
}

//selectPrint
print(greet(person: "Tim", alreadyGretted: true))

//funcD
func greet(guy: String) {
    print("Hello, \(guy)")
}

greet(guy: "Dave")
```

function in funcA and funcB are all sending greetings; funcC will fist check weather a person have been greeted. If so, function in funcA will be invoked otherwise function in funcB will be called.

Now problems comes when I write the function in funcD, The compiler says it confused

[image]

Issue observed:

1. the argument label (defaulted as the parameter name, "guy") is different with all previous functions (shouldn't have the unambiguous problem)
2. the auto fill list from xCode regionalizes this function signature

[image]

3. Although, it gives out the compiler error but the code still complies and seems running correctly

[image]

**Question:** Whether my code is incorrect or the playground in Xcode8 has a bug?

BTW: If the selectPrint line is deleted, the error is gone with it.

Thanks

Comment: Definitely look like a bug to me. If you move `print(greet(person: "Tim", alreadyGretted: true))` to the end, it works fine. If you know something in the language guide that say it's the expected behavior, you are welcome to prove me wrong

Answer (score 0):

The isue is not reproducible with Xcode Verion 9.0 beta 3 (9M174d)